# Crear varias variables con el mismo nombre en PHP

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es crear varias $pieza, que en cada vez que pasan por el segundo for la siguiente $pieza creada sea $pieza1, luego $pieza2, etc... de forma que cada $pieza tenga 4 valores dentro en vez de crear las $pieza necesarias, es decir que se haga de forma automatica cada vez que se llena una $pieza.

Deberia crear un `$pieza1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4]`, `$pieza2 = [3, 5, 6, 8]`, etc, pero a partir de una sola variable creada (`$pieza1`) y que luego en el for hubiese algo como `$pieza[$i]` que fuese incrementando el `$pieza1` al `$pieza2` cada vez que tiene 4 valores dentro del array `$pieza`.

Creo que se entiende lo que quiero decir, si no, por favor preguntarme o sugerir algun cambio en la pregunta, muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

```
<body>
    
    <?php

    $array = [4, 4,
        2, 5, 4, 0,
        2, 1, 4, 2,
        0, 1, 1, 0,
        4, 4, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 4, 3,
        0, 0, 1, 1,
        1, 4, 0, 0,
        4, 4, 3, 5,
        5, 5, 2, 4,
        1, 1, 0, 5,
        4, 1, 0, 4,
        1, 0, 2, 4,
        3, 5, 1, 2,
        1, 4, 2, 0,
        0, 1, 5, 2,
        1, 5, 0, 4];


    function tamanioYpiezas($arrayPiezas){

        $pieza = [];

        $length = count($arrayPiezas);

        $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
        $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];

        for($i = 2; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
            
            array_push($pieza, $arrayPiezas[$i]);

                for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

                    $pieza = [];

                }
        }
        print_r($pieza);
    }

    tamanioYpiezas($array);
    

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola. No, al menos yo no entiendo cuál es el resultado deseado. Trata de plasmarlo en la pregunta. Pusiste ya los datos de prueba (bien) y el código de ejemplo (bien), ahora dinos cómo deberían quedar esos datos

Comment: @Alfabravo asi se entiende?

Comment: Mmmm... la verdad no entendi muy bien tu pregunta, segun yo tienes un array y en base al tamaño del array queres crear variables? si es asi podrias intentar con variables dinamicas o como se le llaman en php variables variables que se representan por $$variable, te pongo un ejemplo si tienes $barcelona = "100", $sevilla = "200", y $ciudad = "barcelona" (ojo aqui, el valor de ciudad es barcelona, y tenemos una variable llamasa igual) y ejecutas echo ${$ciudad}; el resultado sera 100 mientras que si ejecutas $ciudad; el resultado es barcelona; ....

Comment: ... en dado caso que quisieras guardar variables tipo $pieza1 ... $piezaN podrias hacer: foreach($array as $item){ ${"pieza".$item} = "valor deseado";} de esa forma te quedaran variables $pieza1, $pieza2 .... $piezaN que podras usas sin ningun problema o con un for($i = 0; $i < $array.length ; $i++){ ${"pieza".$i} = "valor deseado"; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es la creación de una variable dinámica a través del índice del FOR y la concatenación de una string y una variable, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
${"pieza".$x}
```

Donde si `x=1` el resultado de tu variable dinámica será pieza1, y así mientras incrementes tu índice, X será el índice que vas a incrementar cada que se cumpla tu condición, espero sea lo que buscas.

Comment: muchas gracias raul, era exactamente eso, voy a probarlo

Comment: @daniel ¿hay algo que justifique el tener que *crear* variables en este contexto? ¿no se puede simplemente concatenar y luego imprimir?